# Why HashSet calling compareTo method and causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, collections

I am adding values in `HashSet` and getting `NullPointerException` in `compareTo` method.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fiveIQ.document.Link.compareTo(Link.java:226)
    at com.fiveIQ.document.Link.compareTo(Link.java:16)
    at java.util.HashMap.compareComparables(HashMap.java:371)
    at java.util.HashMap$TreeNode.treeify(HashMap.java:1920)
    at java.util.HashMap.treeifyBin(HashMap.java:771)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:643)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219)
    at com.fiveIQ.crawlData.parser.EightyLegJsonParser.parse(EightyLegJsonParser.java:51)
    at com.fiveIQ.crawlData.processor.CrawlDataParser.process(CrawlDataParser.java:57)
    at com.fiveIQ.crawlData.processor.CrawlDataUploader.upload(CrawlDataUploader.java:31)
    at com.fiveIQ.crawlData.processor.CrawlDataUploaderExecutor$1.run(CrawlDataUploaderExecutor.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my `compareTo` method. Values of `updatedOn` is null. But I am not getting why `HashSet` is calling `compareTo`?

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Link o)
{
    return o.updatedOn.compareTo(this.getUpdatedOn());
}
```

Comment: Irrespective of *why*, it *is*.  Are you sure that `o` isn't `null` when you first go to insert something?

Comment: Your `compareTo` method should not throw an NPE unless the passed argument is `null`, [per the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you are using Java 8. Since Java 8 the `HashMap` implementation (which is used by `HashSet`) is changed to protect against collisions: if the same bucket has too many elements and keys are `Comparable`, then this bucket is converted to the R-B tree (similar to `TreeMap`) to make search in that bucket logarithmic instead of linear. This also protects application from malicious attempts to poison HashMaps with colliding keys causing denial-of-service attacks. See [JEP 180](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Under certain circumstances newer versions of `HashMap` (from Java 8 onwards) try to use a tree as the bin for objects with the same hash code instead of a linked list. It only does it if your objects implement `Comparable`, and it has every right to do so as your objects advertise themselves as being `Comparable`.

**The lesson is: if you implement `Comparable` in your object, your `compareTo()` method must fulfill its contract**, specifically they should only fail with a `NullPointerException` if the argument passed to them is `null`. In your case one of the `Link` objects has `updatedOn` set to `null`, this causes the problem. What you should have instead is something like this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Link o)
{
    if (o.updatedOn == null) {
        return this.updatedOn == null ? 0 : 1; //or -1, depending on whether you want null to come first or last in the ordering
    ]
    return o.updatedOn.compareTo(this.updatedOn); // it isn't a good idea to use getter for one object and direct field access for the other
}
```

This implementation won't fail with a NPE but it still has an issue: what happens if two different links are updated on the same date? What happens is that sometimes they will be treated as equal. At other times they won't. Your code will fail in subtle and unpredictable ways.

The reason for that is that `updatedOn` doesn't contain enough information about `Link` objects to uniquely identify them, it shouldn't be used in `compareTo()` on its own.

**So the second lesson is: be careful to only implement `Comparable` if your objects have a "natural" order that can be derived from their properties. In other words: only objects that can be treated as identical if neither is greater than the other be `Comparable`.**

Comment: There’s one thing that should be mentioned: since the hash-based collection resorts to sorting when there is a certain number of collisions, it might be an indicator for a `hashCode` implementation as poor as the `compareTo` implementation. Improving that is recommended as well…